# Magento 2.1.2 Child-theme front end no display

Tags: theme, magento-2.1.2

I have duplicated the theme in `app` folder and modified the `theme.xml` accordingly. But it displays like below screen shot.

> http://brick.learnup.ro/lux/

[image]

It should be look like this -

> http://brick.learnup.ro/

[image]

I have to mention that I have successfully ran all the commands in SSH:

setup:upgrade
setup:di:compile
cache:flush
setup:static-content:deploy

and set the permissions right.

The problem occurs only with the duplicates of this theme

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was I had forgotten to create the widgets for this new theme - with the "Design Package/Theme" set to it.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the **app & pub** folder of your theme & paste it into your Magento root directory & from there fire the below command

**To set & install the new modules of your theme.**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**To set & make visible the static content of your theme that is css,js,Images.**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

For your convenience & making sure about it that every thing is ready run this command also to remove the cache

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Basically the last command is used for the cache clearing.

Comment: Ok, so I have tried using the initial setup for the theme.

But the problem is elsewhere: the store is either not configured right, or there is another problem which I can't figure out. 
In console I get 

>>Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token   ( index ): 423<<

Comment: You could run this command for such an error `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` & if the problem is still persists than you can ask it in proper manner as an question on the same platform Thank You!